# Find the distance between eyes in Android using FaceDetector.Face

Tags: android, distance, pixel

I want to determine distance between the eye in pixels.
I am using the the below code to calculate the distance.

But I don't think so it it return distance in pixels.

public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {

```
if (faces.length > 0){
```

double leftEye_X = faces[0].leftEye.x;

double leftEye_Y = faces[0].leftEye.y;

double rightEye_X = faces[0].rightEye.x;

double rightEye_Y = faces[0].rightEye.y;

double distance_eyes_square = Math.pow((leftEye_X - rightEye_X),2) + Math.pow((leftEye_Y - rightEye_Y),2);

}

Comment: Did you find out how to achieve that? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Try eyesDistance method of Face class.

Comment: eyeDistance() method return distance in which unit?